# createjs mousedown don not feel fluently

Tags: ios, html, safari, createjs

I wrote a small game with `createjs`. Just mousedown on the `displayObject` and make it hidden.

Every time I mousedown on the object, the canvas will stop for a little while in iOS Safari. How can I fix this problem?

Demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.combined.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function preload(){
    document.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
    var container = new createjs.Container();
    stage.addChild(container);
    var rings = 40;
    var radius = 50;
    var colors = ["#828b20", "#b0ac31", "#cbc53d", "#fad779", "#f9e4ad", "#faf2db", "#563512", "#9b4a0b", "#d36600", "#fe8a00", "#f9a71f"];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      shape = new createjs.Shape();
      for (var j = rings; j > 0; j--) {
        shape.graphics.beginFill(colors[Math.random() * colors.length | 0]).drawCircle(0, 0, radius * j / rings);
      }
      shape.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
      shape.y = $(window).height()+50*Math.random()*20;
      shape.velX = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
      shape.velY = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
      shape.on("mousedown", function () {
        this.visible = false;
        stage.update();
      });
      shape.snapToPixel = true;
      container.addChild(shape);


    }
    createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
    function tick(event) {
      var l = container.getNumChildren() ;
      for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        shape = container.getChildAt(i);
        shape.y = shape.y-5;
        if(shape.y<-250||!shape.visible){
          shape.x = (canvas.width-150) * Math.random();
          shape.y = canvas.height;
          shape.visible = true;
        }
      }
      stage.update(event);
    }
  }



</script>

<body onLoad="preload();">
  <div class="box">
    <canvas id="canvas"  width="640" height="1040"></canvas>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Could it be the call to `stage.update()` that causes the brief delay?

Comment: I tested this in iOS 9.3 on a fairly old device and had no issues. Your `stage.update()` in the mousedown is redundant (you can remove it), and you might consider caching your shapes to improve performance. This code is clearly from the EaselJS cache example, and is meant to be quite heavy since it draws so many vectors each frame.